# Linking image to outside url in WordPress Template

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I've encountered this issue a couple times but have always found a "hack" way around it.  Is there a special way to link an image in a WordPress template to an outside url beyond the typical a href tag?  Here's the images I'm trying to link to outside urls:

```
 <div class="socialMedia">
        Follow Us: <br />
       <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/facebook.png" alt="facebook"/> 
       <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/twitter.png" alt="twitter"/> 
       <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/googleplus.png" alt="google plus"/>
       <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/instagram.png" alt="instagram"/>
        </div><!--.socialMedia-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="socialMedia">
        Follow Us: <br />
    <a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/facebook.png" target="_blank" >   <img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_url') ?>/images/facebook.png" alt="facebook"/> </a>

        </div><!--.socialMedia-->
```

did you mean it!!?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that approach but nothing happens, unless I'm mistaken.  Seems like you need some kind of php statement but I don't know what it is.